# Remove image gallery thumbnail from yahoo pipes in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gallery, yahoo-pipes

hello i building a wordpress site with yahoo pipes, and wp-o-matic plugin
im dealing with blog with lots of pic, and after the picture there is a gallery on every post,
how is the way to remove the gallery(small thumbnail), because at the feed its already gone, but if i read it through google reader or post it to my blog the gallery keep show's up.
thanks.